# Function still running after return

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, electron

I'm adding a colour picker to my Electron app using [RobotJS](https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs), when the user clicks the button a `.click()` triggers my function that focuses on an input (hidden `opacity: 0; height: 0px; width: 0px;`) which acts as a proxy for when the user clicks (`.blur()`) to fetch the colour at cursor location. It then puts that colour in another input field and returns. However, if the user then click back into the returned input field then clicks out, the `.blur()` still triggers. Why is this and how can I prevent it?

```
<input class="clickProxy" style="opacity: 0; height: 0px; width: 0px;" /> 

$('.color_picker').click(function(){
    getColorAtPointer();
});

function getColorAtPointer(){
    $('input[name="colorSample"]').focus();

    $('input[name="colorSample"]').blur(function(){
        var mouse = robot.getMousePos();
        $('input[name="colorSample"]').val('#'+robot.getPixelColor(mouse.x, mouse.y));
        return;
    });
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding the blur event after the user clicks the color picker. You never unbind it so it would continue to fire every time the user leaves the colorSample element. You have a few options.

The best, in my opinion, is to use [.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of blur so the event only fires once.

For Example:

```
function getColorAtPointer(){
    $('input[name="colorSample"]').focus();

    $('input[name="colorSample"]').one("blur", function(){
        var mouse = robot.getMousePos();
        $('input[name="colorSample"]').val('#'+robot.getPixelColor(mouse.x, mouse.y));
        return;
    });
}
```

Alternatively you could namespace the blur event (e.g. `.on("blur.color-picked")` then inside of the blur event handler unbind the event (e.g. `.off("blur.color-picked")`

It is also worth noting that you do not have to use an anonymous function inside of click events, you can pass the function directly

```
$('.color_picker').click(getColorAtPointer);
```

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks!

Comment: Realistically then, there's no need for that `return;` right?

Comment: Correct. The event handler understands a return value of `false`, if you wanted to return it. This should prevent event propagation/bubbling. Of course when you dont call return from a function javascript returns `undefined` for you which is fine here.